# How do I use a variable value as part of the dom tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I understand that I can use eval, but based on what I've read, eval is evil!  Are there alternatives I can use?

```
var key = "foo"; //hardcoded for this example, but should actually be dynamic

console.log(document.myform.foo.value); //prints whatever value its supposed to be

document.myform[key].value = "bar"; //<-- what i want to do

console.log(document.myform.foo.value); //prints "bar"
```

Also have jquery.  Is this something jquery can make easier to manipulate?

Comment: The "eval is evil" mantra came about because it was often used where it was completely unnecessary (e.g. `var a = eval('1 + 2');`). There is nothing inherantly wrong with *eval*, it is quite handy for evaluating arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that script. It will work as you expect. Basically, any time you have a `.` in JavaScript, the value after it can be notated with array notation (which is what you have there)

```
console.log( window.location === window[ 'location' ] ) // true
var loc = 'location';
console.log( window.location === window[ loc ] ) // true
```

Comment: That "array notation" is called (rather clumsily) "the bracket notation" in ECMA-262 §11.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is all about accessing the dom tree, if key is an id you can use jQuery like so:

```
$('#' + key).val();
```

There are a whole host of selectors to make accessing the dome easy with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')...
$('input:radio')...
```

Check-out the selectors link above, its a big part of why jQuery is so nice.